# Suggestions for good resource to learn DAX for Power Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot, dax

Will be transforming current 'data model' utilizing multiple workbooks that have tabs with single queries to Power Pivot data model per workbooks. This is a new topic and want to get suggestions on good resources to learn DAX.

A few titles I have found with pretty good reviews on Amazon are:

- The Definitive Guide to DAX: Business Intelligence with Microsoft Excel, SQL Server... by Alberto Ferrari
- Supercharge Power BI: Power BI Is Better When You Learn to Write DAX, by Matt Allington
- Power Pivot and Power BI: The Excel User's Guide to DAX, Power Query, Power BI... by Rob Collie
- The Definitive Guide to DAX: Business Intelligence for Microsoft Power BI, SQL Server..., by Marco Russo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from reading this forum you can also check [SQLBI's repository](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/) of articles.

The youtube channel [DAX Fridays!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDz00l_jz6zym_YP8ZW11o52niGfCP8pN) gives short pinpoint explanations of how/why DAX works/behaves as it does

SQLBI also have some [free video courses](https://www.sqlbi.com/training/) helping you get started.

In addition, there's a lot of good, informative, and free access materials on the web in the form of blogs etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Oscar. I will look into them.

Comment: Awesome recommendation Oscar! Just looked into SQLBI DAX video courses and they have introduction to DAX and data modelling taught by Marco Russo and
Alberto Ferrari who I believe are the creators of the DAX language.